# How to connect to a third party API from node.js using Express.js

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am trying to connect to a third party api with authorization key but no luck. Any suggestion/direction/comment would be appreciated.

**server.js**

```
...

app.get('/products', (req, res) => {

request.get(BASE_URL, {
  'auth': {
  'bearer': 'abcdsfegete'
}
 }).on('error', function (error) {
    console.log(error);

 }).on('response', function (response) {
    console.log(response);
 })
res.send();
})
...
```

**Result:** I keep getting "This response has to data available".

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be the properties were wrong (`auth`, `bearer`). So basic authentication is used instead.

```
app.get('/products', (req, res) => {
const options = {
url: BASE_URL + '/products',
headers: {
  'Authorization': 'abcdefghghgh',
  'Accept': 'application/json'
}
};
   request.get(options).pipe(res);
})
```